# What's the difference between $|\overrightarrow{v}|$ and $\|\overrightarrow{v}\|$

Tags: notation, scientific-notation

What's the difference between these two signes $|\overrightarrow{v}|$ and $\|\overrightarrow{v}\|$ for a given vector $\overrightarrow{v}$?

Comment: Did you check to see if these were defined in your text?

Comment: They both usually mean the length of the vector. Different texts and teachers use the one they prefer. Personally, I think the double lines version is clearer, but know I might have to deal with the single line version.

Comment: Is $A$ a vector, or is it a matrix? The "usual" notation is $A$ for a matrix and $v$ for a vector of a vector space $V$. For a matrix, $||A||$ is a [matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm).

Comment: Good point, @DietrichBurde. I assumed it was certain we were dealing with a vector, but I'm also used to capital letters being matrices too. With double checking.

Comment: do we have to define these signes before using them?? I mean you don't define "="  as equality sign because it is obvious. I thought it's the same for |...| and ||...||

Comment: @DietrichBurde, just modified my post, to make it clear that $\overrightarrow{v}$ is a vector

Comment: Yes, I think we need to define these "signs". Just now the following post appeared [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4474703/if-u-in-h1-mathbbrn-does-u-in-h1-mathbbrn-and-nabla-u-2). It has the notions $|u|$ and $||\nabla u ||_2$ and so on. I am not sure what exactly is meant without a definition.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, the use of each sign is a covenetional I think, $|...|$ is used for absolute value, or modulus of a complex number, while $||...||$ is used for normes.

Comment: Those conventions are not as strict as you seem to think, which you will discover as your mathematical reading broadens. Keep in mind, the absolute value *IS* an example of a norm, and its "single bar" notation $|...|$ is often applied to more general norms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\overrightarrow v$ is an element of $\mathbb R^n$ for some positive integer $n$, then these two notations are the same: choice of $\|\cdot\|$ or $|\cdot|$  depends on the author.

I specified the meaning of $\overrightarrow v$ above because the word "vector" has many different uses in mathematics.

---

Examples.  If I am talking about $\mathbb R^3$, I may want to use $|\lambda|$ for the absolute value of a scalar and $\|\overrightarrow v\|$ for the norm of a vector.

If I am talking about Hilbert space $L^2(\Omega,\mathbb R^n)$, then I may want ot use $|\overrightarrow v|$ for the norm of $\overrightarrow{v} \in \mathbb R^n$  and $\|\varphi\|$ for the norm of $\varphi \in L^2(\Omega,\mathbb R^n)$.  Like this.
$$
\|\varphi\| := \left(\int_\Omega|\varphi(t)|^2\;dt\right)^{1/2}
$$