# If $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, does $|u|\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\|\nabla u\|_2=\| \nabla|u|\|_2$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Let $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ where $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the standard Sobolev space $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. We already know that if $\Omega$ is a bounded domain, then for any $u\in H^1(\Omega)$, there must holds $u^+,\,u^-,\,|u|\in H^1(\Omega)$. Then it is trivial to know that
$$
\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^2=\int_{\Omega}|\nabla |u||^2.
$$
My question is that does this property still holds for unbounded domain? Especially, if we consider the case $\mathbb{R}^n$, does $|u|\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\nabla u|^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\nabla |u||^2\,\,?
$$
Here is my attempt: Since $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ for any bounded domain $\Omega$. Then we know $|u|\in H^1(\Omega)$. Hence for any test function $\phi\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, there must exists some $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $supp(\phi)\subset\Omega$, then the integral by parts formula holds, and I think we can just conclude that $|u|\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. The $L^2$ norm equality for the gradient $\nabla u$ and $\nabla|u|$ is simple I think, because there hold $u=u^+-u^-$, $|u|=u^++u^-$ and $u^+\cdot u^-\equiv 0$.

Am I right? I think this is a standard attempt but I just can't find a precise theorem for the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$. If there are any errors in the above proof, please just point them out. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go. See also my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4473171/minu-const-is-a-function-in-w1-2

Comment: thank you @daw! I totally get it!